# Hyperlink in Eclipse is not working on click

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, hyperlink, eclipse-rcp

So, I just want to open a simple link in Eclipse. What I did:

```
final Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink(group, SWT.WRAP);
            link.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkAdapter(){
                public void linkActivated(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("test");

            });
            link.setEnabled(true);
            link.setToolTipText("Test tooltip!");
            link.setForeground(new Color(null, 0, 0, 250));
            link.setText("Text");
```

All nice and good, the text appear in my color, but when I click the text I never get the System.out.println("test")...I see the tooltip also. But never enters in the linkActivated method. 
Where I'm wrong ? 
Additional info: this is done in a Dialog->Composite->Group

Thank you in advance!

LE: So sorry for that, the problem was that Eclipse imported automated  *javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent* when I really needed *org.eclipse.ui.forms.events.HyperlinkEvent*.
Again sorry for spam, but it took me some time to find out this.

Comment: You may want to post your edit as the answer and mark it as the answer . People may miss the part that you already solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from above:

> The problem was that Eclipse imported automated `javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent` when I really needed `org.eclipse.ui.forms.events.HyperlinkEvent`.